# Are non-identifying clauses always preceded by names?

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

This information I got from Oxford Grammar by M. Swan, tells me that the difference between **identifying** and **non-identifying clauses** is just whether the topic that the speakers are talking about is conveyed or not.

For instance,

> The book that **got the prize for best first novel** was written by my
> landlady.

The sentence above contains an identifying relative clause.

> 'Wild cherries', **which got the prize for best first novel**, was written by my
> landlady.

Whereas, the second sentence above contains a non-identifying relative clause.

For more examples, here's the screenshot of the e-book I took :

[image]

I notice that the non-identifying relative clauses are preceded by names. Related to my question, if the preceded subject is a name, is it always called a non-identifying clause?

P.s. I've been trying to find a counterexample, i.e. if it's not a name, but I haven't come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-identifying clauses are certainly not always preceded by names. Textbook authors overuse such examples because they create their own context. A name is always "self-identifying," so what follows is always non-identifying.

The following examples illustrate the same principle without using any names. They're a little longer but more characteristic of real sentences. The first is my own invention. I adapted the second from a scientific paper.

> Yesterday, I ran into my professor and the dean of the college. The professor, whom I'd been avoiding for days, pretended to be happy to see me.

> The study showed a significant effect of Facebook browsing on anxiety, which was assessed using a rating-based scale rather than a visual analog scale.

The second has a kind of "self-identifying" quality, because we already know what "anxiety" means, but it's not a name.

By the way, you missed the final example in your e-book, in which **the roses** is identified by the post-modifying phrase **in the living room.**